# What is the most efficient way of copying elements that occur only once in a std vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I have a std vector with elements like this:

```
[0 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 2 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 188 , 220 , 0 , 1 , 2 ]
```

What is the most efficient way to find and copy the elements that occur only once in this vector, excluding the brute force O(n^2) algorithm? In this case the new list should contain `[188, 220]`

Comment: I'd start by sorting it, after that it should be easy.

Comment: ... and if the vector should be constant, and cannot be sorted, copy it to a second vector, then sort that.

Comment: i know this is not exactly what you ask but it made me think of c# linq pipelines - here is c++ version of it http://pfultz2.github.io/Linq/ - and many others (ask google)

Comment: Why would you consider brute-forcing with O(N^2), when sorting is generally O(N.logN), and depending on your data range, there may be an O(N) solution.  Who knows?  You didn't specify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Make an `unordered_map<DataType, Count> count;`
2. Iterate over the input vector increasing count of each value. Sort of `count[value]++;`
3. Iterate over the `count` map copying keys for which value is 1.

It's `O(n)`. You have hashes so for small data sets normal map might be more efficient, but technically it would be `O(n log n)`.

It's a good method for discrete data sets.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v{1,1,2,3,3,4};
    unordered_map<int,int> count;
    for (const auto& e : v) count[e]++;
    vector<int> once;
    for (const auto& e : count) if(e.second == 1) once.push_back(e.first);
    for (const auto& e : once) cout << e << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried few ideas. But I don't see a way around `map`. `unordered_multiset` is almost a great way... except it does not allow you to iterate over keys. It has a method to check for count of key, but you would need another set just for keys to probe. I don't see it as a simpler way. In modern c++ with `auto`s counting is easy. I've also looked through `algorithm` library, but I haven't found any `transfrom`, `copy_if`, `generate`, etc. which could conditionally transform an element (map entry -> value if count is 1).

Comment: Creating and initializing a new data structure is overkill.  You can get the desired behavior through the STL algorithms.

Comment: Please provide an example or at least name the functions. I don't know a `distinct` equivalent in `std`. Or do you mean a filter? I guess one could filter the count map, but it won't give back the original type.

Comment: I take it back, a `std::set` would actually work nicely here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Appreciate it @luk32

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Both of those are O(n log n) though, and using an unordered_map is O(n).

Comment: @Dan It's _amortized_ `O(n)`.  That means for small n or certain patterns of data, it can be slower.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez If you really want to nitpick, remember, that Big-O describes asymptotic behaviour and doesn't have sense for small `n`.

Comment: @luk32 Yes, exactly.  However, this problem _does_ make sense for small `n`, and it's why I'm "nitpicking."  I'm not trying to say your answer is bad, I'm trying to say that it's not perfect.  Future readers that come to look at this answer should know that, and think twice about their data before picking an algorithm.

Comment: @Brian Rodriguez and set and other tree based data structures very often have horrible pre factors because of pointer chasing. I don't see the point of the nit picking. Actually I'd be tempted to wager that set/map is always slower than just sorting the vector in place and doing a single traversal, they're both nlogn but the vector is more cache friendly.

Comment: @luk32 In the line "for (const auto& e : v) count[e]++" the value part of the map "count" are all initialized to zero? Is this the documented behaviour?

Comment: Sure it's convoluted, but it works like this. When you use [`operator_at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) if they key does not exists it's inserted and the mapped value is default initialized. That is why `mapped_type` has to be default constructible.

Answer (score 8):

There are very few universally-optimal algorithms.  Which algorithm works best usually depends upon the properties of the data that's being processed.  Removing duplicates is one such example.

Is `v` small and filled mostly with unique values?

```
auto lo = v.begin(), hi = v.end();
std::sort(lo, hi);
while (lo != v.end()) {
    hi = std::mismatch(lo + 1, v.end(), lo).first;
    lo = (std::distance(lo, hi) == 1) ? hi : v.erase(lo, hi);
}
```

Is `v` small and filled mostly with duplicates?

```
auto lo = v.begin(), hi = v.end();
std::sort(lo, hi);
while (lo != v.end()) {
    hi = std::upper_bound(lo + 1, v.end(), *lo);
    lo = (std::distance(lo, hi) == 1) ? hi : v.erase(lo, hi);
}
```

Is `v` *gigantic*?

```
std::unordered_map<int, bool> keyUniqueness{};
keyUniqueness.reserve(v.size());
for (int key : v) {
    bool wasMissing = keyUniqueness.find(key) == keyUniqueness.end();
    keyUniqueness[key] = wasMissing;
}
v.clear();
for (const auto& element : keyUniqueness) {
    if (element.second) { v.push_back(element.first); }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: With all due respect, I prefer myversion =P. More concise, and readable. For small data sets, or memory footprint one can always rebound to a "normal" map. With map you get automatic sort and take care of dupes. Your version is good for huge vectors with no dupes because it could possibly work in place if sort does.

Comment: @luk32 Unfortunately, the OP hasn't asked for readability.  They've asked for efficiency.  And the truth is: your answer is not the solution.  That's because **there is no solution**.  It's very important to understand that.

Comment: Could you explain the third block of code? "i.e: when the vector is ginormous"

Comment: @SRINI794 Over 1 million elements is a good example of ginormous.

Comment: It's better always except for huge vectors with no dupes only if you are memory constrained, and only if std::sort works in-place. I cannot find such a constraint in cppreference =/. It does have a great educational value, though. And it's good that it's present and discussed, IMHO. It does cover a valid case I guess.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot guys :) Much appreciated. Yeah, in some cases I might end up having a vector with more million elements.  If I could i would upvote you both.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't take any of our advice until you benchmark them in your program.  C++ is not like other languages where throwing away efficiency for readability is fine, unless you really just don't care.  But your question implies you do, so **test that it's the fastest!**  Run a sample program and try each approach out!  This is how making C++ run as fast as possible goes.

Comment: @luk32 You're looking at the *amortized* costs of `unordered_map`.  You should remember that there may be some huge constant in front of that `O(1)` that makes it slower than these approaches.  Algorithms are almost never black-and-white better or worse than each other.  **It will depend on the type of data being processed.**  For example: With small lists, _bubble sort is faster than quick-sort_!

Comment: Your second example is just a convoluted version of a simple count map. Can you describe advantages of using this logic: key not-present -> `count == 0`, `key == true` -> `count == 1`, `key == false` -> `count > 1`? I don't think the storage is an issue, you probably won't be able to store single bits.

Comment: @luk32 The `bool` represents whether the key is unique.  When inserted for the first time, it is flagged as "unique."  If it is found again later on, it is flagged as "not-unique."

Comment: I'm not asking to explain the logic, I understood it. It's the same as counting, you just flatten `count > 1` into `false`. I am asking what is the reason to complicate the implementation. I cannot spot the gain. Or just to present a different approach? Cheers.

Comment: @luk32 I simplified it, so it should be much more expressive now.

Answer (score 1):

@luk32's answer is definitely the most time efficient way of solving this question. However, if you are short on memory and can't afford an `unordered_map`, there are other ways of doing it.

You can use `std::sort()` to sort the vector first. Then the non-duplicates can be found in one iteration. Overall complexity being `O(nlogn)`.

If the question is slightly different, and you know there is only one non-duplicate element, you can use [this code](http://techinterviewsolutions.net/2014/09/30/find-non-repeating-element-in-an-array/) (code in Java). The conplexity here is `O(n)`.

Comment: I'd hold back from using such bold statements.  `unordered_map` is a good solution when there are a huge number of elements.  If the number is small, there are much more efficient ways of handling the data.

Comment: I agree with you, `unordered_map` most definitely the best way. I just wanted to add two more solutions in case for some reason the user can't use another data structure. Such situations might arise in interview questions. I remember I was asked an interview question where I have to implement a stack which keeps track of it's maximum value. I also couldn't push anything other than the value itself into the stack. Caught me off guard.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a `std::vector`, I presume you want to maximize all its benefits including [reference locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). In order to do that, we need a bit of typing here. And I benchmarked the code below...

I have a linear `O(n)` algorithm here (effectively `O(nlog(n))`), its a bit like brian's answer, but I use [OutputIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) instead of doing it in-place. The pre-condition is that it's sorted.

---

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator single_unique_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result){
    auto previous = first;
    if(previous == last || ++first == last) return result;
    while(true){
        if(*first == *previous)
            while((++first != last) && (*first == *previous));
        else
            *(result++) = *previous;
        if(first == last) break;
        previous = first;
        ++first;
    }
    return ++result;
}
```

And here is a sample usage:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> vm = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 88, 220, 0, 1, 2, 227, -8};
    std::vector<int> kk;
    std::sort(vm.begin(), vm.end());
    single_unique_copy(vm.begin(), vm.end(), std::back_inserter(kk));
    for(auto x : kk) std::cout << x << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output is:

```
-8, 88, 220, 227
```

Your use case may be different from mine, so, profile first... :-)

EDIT:

- Using luk32's algorithm and mine... Using 13 million elements...
  created in descending order, repeated at every `i % 5`.
- Under debug build, luk32: `9.34`seconds and mine: `7.80`seconds
- Under -O3, luk32: `2.71`seconds and mine `0.52`seconds
- Mingw5.1 64bit, Windows10, 1.73Ghz Core i5 4210U, 6GB DDR3 1600Mhz RAM
- Benchmark here, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/187e5e3841439742

For smaller numbers, the difference still holds, until it becomes a non-critical code