# finding the most repeated elements in an array with length n

Tags: c++, arrays

```
  const int N=10;

  int main()
  {

    int arr[N]={4,4,6,4,6,6,7,9,9,9};

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])

              cout << arr[i];
        }


    return 0;
 }
```

This gives all the repeated elements (meaning it will give 444,666,999). My problem is that I want the output to be just 4,6,9 and not that 4 was repeated three times. Obviously I gave my global constant a value of 10 but how can i do this for an "n" (unknown) number. Thanks.

Comment: Store them in a `std::set` and then output the sets contents?

Comment: so make an inventory. `for(...) { inventory[arr[i]]++; }` (count how many of each value shows up), then sort the inventory and pick off the top X elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate?? Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215773/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-copying-elements-that-occur-only-once-in-a-std

Comment: @MarcB's comment is the right way to go if the range of the numbers in the array is small.  What is the range of the number in the array?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning sort array

```
sort(arr, arr + n);
```

Then iterate and find the count of the most repeated element, you can do that like this :

```
int maxCnt = 0;
int curCnt = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
 if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) curCnt++;
 else 
   {
     maxCnt = max(maxCnt, curCnt);
     curCnt = 1;
   }
}
maxCnt = max(maxCnt, curCnt);
```

then iterate again accumulating curCnt and when curCnt == maxCnt output number

```
curCnt = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
 if (curCnt == maxCnt) cout << arr[i - 1] << ' ';
 if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
   curCnt++;
 }
 else curCnt = 1;
}
if (curCnt == maxCnt) cout << arr[n - 1] << endl;
```

This solution will output the most repeated numbers only once.

Answer (score 0):

- Use "range based for loop" for unknown array size (N).
- Use `std::map` to calculate the count for each element.

Here is the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int arr[]{ 4,4,6,4,6,6,7,9,9,9 };

    // Get count for each element.
    map<int, int> elementCount;
    for (const auto& e : arr)
    {
        elementCount[e] += 1;
    }

    // Get the highest count.
    int highestCount = 0;
    for (const auto& e : elementCount)
    {
        cout << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;
        if (e.second > highestCount)
        {
            highestCount = e.second;
        }
    }

    // Get the elements with the hightest count.
    cout << endl << "Elements with the hightest count:" << endl;
    for (const auto& e : elementCount)
    {
        if (e.second == highestCount)
        {
            cout << e.first << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```